# How to find out the keyword in ace-editor

Tags: keyword, ace-editor

For ace-editor, I want to select one line and find out all the keywords within the line and output into the console. Which APIs from ace-editor that I can use for this purpose, and how to achieve the goal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `session.getTokens` method like so

```
var row = editor.selection.getCursor().row
editor.session.getTokens(row).filter(function(t) {
    return t.type == "keyword"
})
```